# Why it always happens with me?

Tags: vedas, shiva, krishna, mantras, meditation

After consulting you guys many time on how to start spiritual journey I decided to chant ashttotar satnamavali of my deity,I decided to chant one name every night before sleeping for 108 days I even did it everyday for a 8 days  today is the 9th day and I'm extremely sick,having high fever,so much cough that my throat is hurting while talking everytime I decide to do meditation/ajapa japa/chanting something like this happen
It's been happening to me over and over again tell me what shall I do also pls tell me should I chant the name today or take a break

Comment: Like any library, Hinduism Stack Exchange shares great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from any Acharya, Pundit, astrologer, Guru or other trustworthy Counselor.

Comment: Maybe take a break and then when you have no cough fever and more feeling better, come back to it with the chanting more carefully and cautious, going slowly 

Comment: @devibhakt  Ok thnks